# $A+\vec x={\{\vec a+\vec x:\vec a\in A\}}$ is an open set in $\Bbb R^n$.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Let $A\subseteq \Bbb R^n$ an open set and let $\vec x\in \Bbb R^n$ a fixed vector. Show that the set $A+\vec x={\{\vec a+\vec x:\vec a\in A\}}$ is an open set in $\Bbb R^n$.

Dem:

An element of the set $A+\vec x$ is of the form $\vec a+\vec x$ for some $\vec a\in A$ and because $A$ is an open set:

$\implies \forall \vec a\in A, \exists\epsilon\gt 0:B(\vec a,\epsilon)\subseteq A$:

$\implies \forall \vec{\alpha}\in A, \exists\epsilon\gt 0:\lVert\vec{\alpha}-\vec a\rVert\lt\epsilon$

Then, $B(\vec a+\vec x,\epsilon)\subseteq A$:

$\implies \forall \vec{\alpha}\in A,\exists \epsilon \gt 0:\lVert\vec{\alpha} - (\vec a+\vec x)\rVert\lt\epsilon$

$\implies \lVert \vec{\alpha} - \vec a-\vec x\rVert\lt\epsilon$

I don't know what follows. Can you help me? I'll appreciate any feedback. Thanks

Comment: You are working in $\mathbb{R}^n$ so open mapping theorem can be applied directly.

Comment: @WilliamZheng This is overkill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $y\in A+x$.

$\implies \exists a\in A,  y=a+x$.

$\implies$ Since $A$ is open $\exists \epsilon>0$, s.t $B(a, \epsilon)
\subset A$.

Now claim $B(y, \epsilon)\subset A+x$.

Let $t\in B(y, \epsilon)$.

$\implies |y-t|<\epsilon $

$\implies |a+x-t|<\epsilon$ or $|a-(t-x)|<\epsilon$

$\implies t-x\in B(a, \epsilon)\subset A$.

$\implies t\in A+x$.

$\implies B(y, \epsilon)\subset A+x$.

Comment: Why can you claim that $B(y,\epsilon)\subset A+x$?

Comment: Intuition if we consider geometrically

Answer (score 2):

$A+\vec x=$[$f^{-1}(A)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(mathematics)#Inverse_image) where the translation $f:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^n,\;\vec y\mapsto\vec y-\vec x$ is continuous (it is even an [isometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometry)).

Since [the inverse image of an open subset by a continuous function is open](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Continuous_functions_between_topological_spaces), $A+\vec x$ is open.